# number and letter binary tree in java

Tags: java, collections

I am creating a binary tree with both numbers and letters using an interface. I have added all the letters however when I try to add the numbers to the letter nodes using the add method, I get a "The method add(Node) in the type Collection> is not applicable for the arguments (int)" error.

The interface methods are;

```
public void addChild(Node<treeNode> child);
public void addChild(int i);
```

The implemented methods are;

```
@Override
public void addChild(Node<treeNode> child) {
    children.add(child); // delegation      
}

@Override
public void addChild(int i) {
    children.add(i);    
}
```

The parent node code, which is in a class on its own, would look like this;

```
Node<String> H = new NodeImplement<String>("H", S, "left");
S.addChild(H);
```

The number nodes I am trying to add look like this

```
Node<String> 5 = new NodeImplement<String>("5", H, "left");
H.addChild(5);

Node<String> 4 = new NodeImplement<String>("4", H, "right");
H.addChild(4);
```

Do I have to parse this somehow? One of the options I get from eclipse is to "Change method addChild(Node child) to addChild(int)" but that will compromise the letters of the alphabet that are in place already.

Comment: How are you able to name your variable `Node<String> 5` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the number where the specified String is, spell the number out and then add it as a String

```
Node<String> five = new NodeImplement<String>("5", H, "left");
H.addChild(five);

Node<String> four = new NodeImplement<String>("4", H, "right");
H.addChild(four);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got the error: 
*The method add(Node) in the type Collection> is not applicable for the arguments (int)" error*
Is because you are passing an integer into a method that requires an object of type Node.

Does you tree have letters as names for the nodes and numbers as values? That is what it looks like to me. Assuming this is the case what you can do is have a class Node. The class has an attribute *int value* , *Node left* , *Node right* . If it doesnt have a left/right node then those attributes will be null.

So when you add the number 5 to a node, what you do is add a node which has a value of 5.
Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your "number nodes" are actually String nodes. It even says Node. Remove the addChild(int i) from your interface and your class. That should solve the problem. Note however that your numbers are represented by Strings.

If you want different Types in the same tree you would have to make an Interface and let all Types implement it.

```
Interface NodeType {
}

class NodeTypeString implements NodeType {
  private String string;

  public NodeTypeString(String string) {
    this.string = string;
  }

  public String getString() {
    return string;
  }
}

class NodeTypeNumber implements NodeType {
  private int number;

  public NodeTypeNumber(int number) {
    this.number=number;
  }

  public int getNumber() {
    return number;
  }
}
```

You can the use it like so:

```
NodeTypeNumber number = new NodeTypeNumber(5);
Node<NodeType> numberNode = new NodeImplement<NodeType>(number, H, "left");

NodeTypeString string = new NodeTypeString("foo");
Node<NodeType> stringNode = new NodeImplement<NodeType>(string, S, "right");
S.addChild(H);
```

Also the Tree would obviously be `Tree<NodeType>`

The other option would be to use `Tree<Object>` as you can store any Object inside. I would advise against it though because it's prone to errors.